# adjusting custom uiview nib size to the size of the uiview in interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to create a custom object with interface builder. I created the object, and my plan was to add a UIView to the main view controller in which I want the object to reside. So, I dragged a UIView object into IB and went to identity inspector. I changed it to the name of my custom UIView. I expected the view to adjust its frame size to fit the frame of the object within the main view controller, but for some reason, it's not. It just appears white. I tried adding it to the view programmatically, and that worked, but i wanted to be able to do everything from interface builder, for AutoLayout purposes. Is there a way to do this? I've seen it done with the Facebook login button. simply add a UIView to the view controller, put it where you want it, change the class type in identity inspector, and it will conform to that size, while displaying the facebook login button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you initialize your UIView subclass? Using `initWithFrame:`? UIViews created on interface builder are instantiated by the `initWithCoder:` method, try using that one instead. In previous implementations of mine, that was the issue.

Comment: so i shouldnt have to add any init code at all within the main VC? just within the custom object's nib file itself right? i added initWithCoder but it didnt work. still white. is there anything specific that should go into that method? heres what i have: - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return [self initWithFrame:[self frame]];
}
also, should i include the NSCoding delegate or anything?

Comment: better yet, do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your previous comment. That's what's wrong. You're initializing the component with `initWithCoder:` and kind of initializing it again with `initWithFrame:`. Try replacing your `return [self initWithFrame:[self frame]];` with a simple `return self;`. Inits should always return the `self` object.

Comment: its still coming up a blank white view. i shouldnt need to put any other code in the main VC right? i wish i knew why this wasnt working :S

Comment: You shouldn't need any other code in the VC. Do you have your `drawRect:` working? Maybe the layout itself is correct, but you're just drawing it blank, or drawing outside its clipped bounds, or even not drawing at all. Start with some simple drawing, like filling the background of the CGRect with a simple color.

Comment: are you changing the view's background color or something? otherwise, it WILL be blank (or transparent, I don't remember exactly).